# Can know protocol And can see the data in the protocol?

Tags: networking, ip-camera, iot

I have an ip camera connected by lan cable to pc.

My PC has a program that allows I can see face data and temperature values, **I want to know value of temperature What protocol is it sent using?**, **And can I see the information contained in the protocol?**

Comment: Please add make and model of the camera and the software you are using. Most IP cameras support the ONVIF protocol.

Comment: @StarCat ...model is CM91H and Sofware program name is CMS-9100. but I want to know protocal   and data for develop